# How to flip a sprite in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm trying to flip a sprite in SpriteKit. it can be done in cocos2d with CCOribitCamera like this:

```
id firstAction = [CCOrbitCamera actionWithDuration:d/2 radius:1 deltaRadius:0 angleZ:0            deltaAngleZ:90 angleX:0 deltaAngleX:0];
id secondAction = [CCOrbitCamera actionWithDuration:d/2 radius:1 deltaRadius:0 angleZ:270     deltaAngleZ:90 angleX:0 deltaAngleX:0];

[self runAction: [CCSequence actions:firstAction,
[ImageSwapAction actionWithCard: self],
secondAction, nil]];
```

Any ideas?

--Added--
Thanks for nickfalk's answer, I figured it out.

```
[sprite runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
                                          [SKAction scaleXTo:0 duration:0.2],
                                          [SKAction runBlock:^{
            [sprite swapImage];
        }],
                                          [SKAction scaleXTo:1 duration:0.2]
                                          ]]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the node's xScale property:

```
spriteInstance.xScale = -1;
```